# Is there ready functionality in Quarkus to provide REST endpoint with artifact version (via git.properties or something else)?

Tags: rest, quarkus

I know SpringBoot has functionality to provide deployed artifact version/commit info using [Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.info.git-commit-information)'s `/info` (or something similar) endpoint, the information comes from a `git.properties` file generated upon build/packaging from git tag/git describe.

Is there similar functionality in Quarkus? Or would it be expected for me to build my own?

Comment: I don't know about this functionality and I think at the moment is expected to be built by you, even you you can always ask for it via a github feature request issue. Having that into account its quite easy to develop this feature, you just have to read your MANIFEST which is bundled whithin the jar and expose the content.

Comment: I would still load from git.properties instead of messing with MANIFEST files

Comment: Your choise, if its bundled within the jar you are fine. If not you can always read it from an external source or a pom file